# How to approach user documentation in a maintainable, but user-friendly way?

Tags: documentation

**Question**

What approach should be taken when designing end-user documentation for a large/corporate (web-based) software system?  Is there industry best-practice that combines good UX with maintainability?

I'm hoping for an answer that focusses on advice for how documentation should be organised and how it should be distributed.

I realise this is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663728/how-do-you-approach-documentation-external-not-in-code-documentation, although that question is primarily related to documentation for an in-house system, or development documentation, rather than customer-facing/user-facing documentation.

**Background**

I'm doing a review on documentation for a software system.  I put web-based in brackets above, because it may or may not impact on the answer... Currently the documentation is a mess of large PDF files and I'm fairly sure none of our users read them.  I believe that having bad documentation causes us extra support.

I believe my end result needs the following (although the question partly covers whether this is correct):

- **User** documentation that provides help on what features are available
  and how they work.
- **Admin** documentation on how to setup the system for first-time use and
  how the administrative features work (e.g. user/record maintenance).
- An **installation** guide, because it has several components (some of which are optional) and there is no automated installer.

The system is updated on a reasonably regular basis with new features, and the documentation needs to reflect the changes to existing features, or detail any new features.

I'm currently considering web-based documentation for the user and administrator guides - i.e. something like a wiki (but read-only), which is searchable and can easily be added to.

I've found the following question on SE that suggests it's possible to export a wiki to a read-only HTML format: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23143/how-to-export-all-pages-from-mediawiki-to-hierarchy-of-html-files, but I still need to do more research into different types of wiki and the export tools available...  Also, if the export tools don't produce a user-friendly result, the whole exercise is pointless.

Comment: Evernote is certainly an option I would consider. You have great flexibility to decide the rigidity and structure of your IA, is very simple to maintain/edit by anyone, and is managable on mobile. Great search functionality as well.

Comment: Reading through your post again, this solution is best for smaller teams rather than large corporate systems.

Comment: This is really a technical writing question, which is a field unto itself. Alas, I don't think we have a tech writing SE site...

Comment: Thanks @DA01, I was wary of posting this question here, as it didn't seem a 100% match for UX.SE.  But I'm after documentation that is easy to read and search, which is all UX :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would actually suggest you set up WordPress or Joomla. Although not its normal use it will allow you to update information quickly and easily.

- Updates to the UI can be made easily and apply to all immediately
- You could restrict via password access and have different levels
- You could use this as a intranet system only, or allow it to be accessed from where ever
- It is very easy to set up searches and tag based systems
- Support ticket systems can easily be supported
- The system can easily be backed up, maintained and data can be exported very easily in to future systems

I know this doesn't fully answer your questions but it seams as though thinking outside the box here could help you out.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using blogging software, but the benefits you've highlighted to this approach do match up to the kind of thing I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tim.

Additionally, you can create this as part of an [Intranet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intranet) that can be updated and maintained on the go. You can structure it like an FAQ or Knowledge-base with a predictive search.

Microsoft does this as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe using a wiki is a great way to organize and distribute documentation, as it let's people contribute and give readers the opportunity to provide feedback. My favorite solution would be [Atlassian's Confluence wiki](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence). It is a great tool for documentation, because it comes with great collaboration features and there are a range of add-ons that help managing and publishing the documentation.

Comment: I am using Atlassian's Confluence wiki and I am missing the capability to add numbers on top of the wireframe, so that if I want to refer to a specific part of the UI, I can place a small circle with number on the wireframe image and place an explanation with the same number on the side.
another problem is that I have to use screen shoots to show my screens and every time there is a small change I need to export all of them again, I would prefer to use a link.